# Unable to associate phonenumber to firebase user using Admin REST Api

Tags: firebase-authentication

In firebase Authentication, I have enabled `Email/Password` and `Phone` providers as Sign-in providers. I am creating users using `Admin REST APIs`.

This is how my payload looks like to `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/signUp`:

```
{
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "password": "12345",
  "phoneNumber": "+15555555555",
  "displayName": "user1",
  "returnSecureToken": True
}
```

This works fine I can see that the user gets created. However, when I do a `lookup` query, I am not getting phoneNumber back in the response.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password) doesn't suggest that phoneNumber is a valid option.  If you think the documentation is wrong, I suggest filing feedback for that using the link at the top of the page.  If you think the API is not doing the correct thing, then file a ticket with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).  We can't help you in either case.

Comment: Oh I see. I was looking at the Identity Platform Admin REST Api while I am using Firebase Authentication. It says I need to upgrade to Identity Platform. I understand that Firebase Authentication is Legacy and Identity Platform is recommended? I hope they don't send me $5k bill for upgrading.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "recommended". If you don't need the extra features of Identity Platform, then just don't upgrade?

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info. Appreciate that.

Comment: I upgraded my project to Identity Platform and according to the documentation here at https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signUp, I should be able to pass phoneNumber which I did but still I am not able to retrieve it in the response.